# Dúvidas sobre execução de Função em Angular/IONIC

Tags: angular, ionic

Estou estudando Angular com IONIC e tenho umas questões sobre execução de função e gostaria de saber se alguem tem como me explicar:
Tenho essa função:

```
public faltas: number;
public selectFalta(): any{
        //this.faltas =  11;
        this.databaseService.getDB()
        .then((db:SQLiteObject) =>{
            let sql = "select count(*) as total from agenda where vch_situacao = '1'";
            let data: any[];
            console.log("Agenda_DAO - selectFalta - SQL: "+sql);
            db.executeSql(sql,data).then((data) =>{
                if(data.rows.length > 0){
                    let temp = data.rows.item(0);
                    this.faltas = temp.total;
                    //this.faltas =  13;
                    return this.faltas;
                    console.log("Agenda_DAO - selectFalta: Encontrou Faltas: "+this.faltas);
                }else{
                    console.log("Agenda_DAO - selectFalta: Não encontrou faltas");
                }
            }).catch(e => {
                console.log("Erro Select: No Exec "+e);
            });
        }).catch(e=>{
            console.error("Erro Select: Sem DB "+e);

        });
        console.log("Agenda_DAO - Faltas: "+this.faltas);
        //this.faltas =  13;
        return this.faltas;
    }
```

O problema é que na chamada:

```
if(data.rows.length > 0){
  let temp = data.rows.item(0);
  this.faltas = temp.total;
```

ele acha o valor e atribui, (`console.log("Agenda_DAO - selectFalta: Encontrou Faltas: "+this.faltas); aqui mostra o valor retornado`) só que qdo eu chamo esse valor numa variavel em outra pagina, ele vem nulo. Ex:

`let flt = this.Agenda_DAO.selectFalta();` //em outras páginas do sistema não retorna nd

A função, não pára o processamento no 1º return, ele continua executando? Parece que a execução dentro do   "then" não tem efeito, ele zera a variável this.faltas depois q sai do then?
Como retorno esse valor e tenho acesso em outra página?

Venho de desenvolvimento em PHP e estou com muitas dificuldades nesses aspectos de retornos de execução de função.